# Image resized with Python PIL are darker

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

I'm  fairly new to PIL and having issue with some image processing. I'm just trying to resize an image to a different resolution using PIL:

```
resized_hd = image.resize((hd_width, hd_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

However, the resized picture does not look as good/bright as the original one.

Original (5184*3456) -> http://d31d9cjolqcwln.cloudfront.net/San+Francisco/sutro+baths.jpg
Resized (2048*1366) -> http://d31d9cjolqcwln.cloudfront.net/San+Francisco/HD-sutro+baths.jpg

Any guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuddo to Armin for his suggestion.

Pil allow you to attach an ICC profile to a resized image using the following code:

```
    icc_profile = im1.info.get('icc_profile')
    im6 = im1.resize((hd_width, hd_height), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    ## this one will preserve the colours
    im6.save("colorok-"+image,icc_profile=icc_profile)
    ## this one don't
    im6.save("nop-"+image)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because one of the two images (the original one) has an embedded color profile, which the other one (the resized one) doesn't have.  I discovered this by trying to open the original image in gimp.  The color profile will cause advanced viewers to make corrections, in theory to fix differences like the ones between paper and screen.  When I view the two images in a simple viewer that doesn't know about color profiles, they are really the same brightness.  It looks like the PIL library ignores the color profile and doesn't carry it onto the resized image.

I can't help you more precisely than that, though, as I don't know much about color profiles.  There might be tools to copy the profile over.